# How does Python IDE IDLE shows autocompletion list on top of text widget at cursor position?

Tags: tkinter, python-idle

Is it using listbox? context-menu? inserting widgets within text? something else?

Also, is there some documentation about how IDLE functions? Which python files do what, etc?

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading this article: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/idle.html, and then you should have a look at the module `idlelib` of your Python distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `autocompletewindow` is a tk `Toplevel` with a `Listbox` and `Scrollbar`. Code is in idlelib/AutoCompleteWindow.py (and associated code in AutoComplete.py).

The Idle doc gives a user view of Idle. There is no doc giving a programmer view of idlelib. (I wish there had been one when I started with Idle. Now that I understand what most of the files do, I should write something.)

EDIT: Tk and Toplevel widgets are located with respect to the desktop by passing a [geometry string](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html) to the `.geometry` (== `.wm_geometry`) method.  Note that the 'wxh' part of the string can be omitted to just pass '+x+y', as in the Idle code.

`CallTipWindow.position_window` calculates x and y from [widget.winfo_rootx/y](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) and [Text.bbox](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) and an offset. If the calltip is triggered by typing `(`, the box is around that character. `AutoCompleteWindow.winconfig_event` does something similar, but also uses `winfo_width/height` methods.

EDIT 2: Popup menus can be positioned with Menu.post(x, y), (or Menu.tk_popup) where x, y are relative to root. [(Working example)](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html#popupmenus)

Comment: Is there any example showing how to show Toplevel on certain position of text widget? Is it lots of code of can it be reproduced easily?

Comment: Yes, it would be very helpful for people wanting to learn how IDLE works and to make some interesting projects by learning to use tkinter. PS: I didn't see that you updated answer in my feed. Please comment next time after updating your answer.