# Using Tkinter Idle Autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, tkinter, python-idle

I want to use AutoCompleteWindow from idlelib, but I can't figure out how to call it or run it (even after reading the code).

Basically I want to have Tab completion, similar to the one used by Idle, on a textbox, using the text from a specific dictionary rather than from main, when pressing Tab.

It seems that I'd have to use the open_completions function from AutoComplete, while modifying fetch_completions to get the namespace from a place other than  "namespace = **main**.**dict**.copy()".  However I couldn't write a functional example.

The docs don't seem have code documentation about idle: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/idle.html, and the only related question here on stackoverflow is this one [How does Python IDE IDLE shows autocompletion list on top of text widget at cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361792/how-does-python-ide-idle-shows-autocompletion-list-on-top-of-text-widget-at-curs)

Comment: 1. The features and functions of IDLE the application are half-way decently documented in the doc chapter you linked.  However, idlelib is not a library in the usual stdlib sense.  It is the implementation package for the application.  The APIs are open but private in that they are intentionally not documented and are subject to change.  Think of most every name as having an invisible `_` prefix.  That said, the near absence of documentation makes it hard to work on IDLE.  So I have added doc strings to some modules and plan more.  The most recent releases have a new README.txt about the files

Comment: 2. To be a proper SO question, you should show some minimal code that exhibits the problem you have and explain what you would like to have it do versus what it does do.  The text explanation you gave is not clear without code. SO is for helping you revise code, not for writing it for you. Note in regard to 1. above.  You should copy into your directory the idlelib code you use, either now or after an initial prototype that imports from idlelib, and not depend indefinitely upon any of the current details.  The may change before 3.6, in about a year.

Comment: 3. Two problems with copying: a) you miss any subsequent bug fixes and enhancements (there are 8 auto completion issues on bugs.python.org), and b ) you also have to copy dependencies in idlelib.  You would not need idleConf, but without some rewriting, would need idlelib.HyperParser, which needs idlelib.PyParse.  I am hoping that idlelib.Multicall (a Text wrapper) is not needed, as I would like to be able to do completion in Entry widgets. It might be easier to use the files as are, if that is possible for what you want to do, and revise your code if and when API changes.

Comment: 4. Autocomplete basically works by creating a sorted list of possible completions and using binary search to find first string matching prefix entered so far.  I am not sure how your specific dictionary fits into this.